# Missing GPO "Allow job name in event logs" in Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, printer

I am using Windows Server 2012 R2 (6.3.9600 Build 9600) for two different servers. However, one server has the GPO option "Allow job name in event logs" while the other one does not.

I have examined the hotfixes for both servers, and I could not see any difference.

I am confused by this situation and could not figure out the solution to make the option "Allow job name in event logs" appear for the server without that option. Thank you in advance.

[Allow job name in event logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WPKf.jpg)
[Missing the gpo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEnRu.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update you server to the current state. Install all updates from Microsoft Update. This way I solved a similar bug.

If this doesn't help, try to patch registry:

```
Registry Hive   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
Registry Path   Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Printers
Value Name  ShowJobTitleInEventLogs
Value Type  REG_DWORD
Enabled Value   1
Disabled Value  0
```

[Allow job name in event logs registry key](http://winintro.com/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Printing::ShowJobTitleInEventLogs)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to resolve this by copying the entire "C:\Windows\Policy Definitions" folder from the server with this setting to the server without it.

Even better would be to implement the [Central Group Policy Store](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2011/12/12/how-to-implement-the-central-store-for-group-policy-admin-templates-completely-hint-remove-those-adm-files/) so that the policy definitions are stored in sysvol and all group policy management consoles in the domain will use the same set of policy templates.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. To resolve this issue, please install [KB2919355](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2919355.)